# how to create javascript array from tcl array

Tags: tcl, adp

please assist me in this ,,,

I have a tcl array called all_tags ,, but the thing is i need to convert it into a javascript array in my page but i am weak when it comes to javascript .

please advise me if below is correct and if not ,,what is the right way ?

```
<script>
var mytags = new Array();
<% 
foreach tag $all_tags {
     ns_puts [subst {
         mytags.push('$tag');
         }]
}
%>
</script>
```

and afterwards is it possible to use my javascript array in a tcl proc ?

Comment: Is it an array or a list? Tcl arrays are more like JS objects than JS arrays (which are in turn more like Tcl lists).

Comment: well it was a tcl array but now I have turned it into a tcl list of 
{{key value} {key value} ....} ,,and I need to turn it into javascript  array of key and value ,, can you help me with that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn data in Tcl into JSON, you want the [`json::write`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json_write.html) package from Tcllib. You'd use it like this to make a JSON object from a Tcl array (and a similar approach works for Tcl dictionaries):

```
package require json::write

set accumulate {}
foreach {key value} [array get yourArray] {
    lappend accumulate $key [json::write string $value]
}
set theJsonObject [json::write object {*}$accumulate]
```

To turn a Tcl list into a JSON array:

```
package require json::write
set accumulate {}
foreach item $yourList {
    lappend accumulate [json::write string $value]
}
set theJsonArray [json::write array {*}$accumulate]
```

Note in these two cases I've assumed that the values are all to be represented as JSON strings. If the values to embed are numbers (or `true` or `false`) you don't need to do anything special; the values as Tcl sees them work just fine as JSON literals. Embedding lists/arrays/dicts takes “recursive” use of `json::write` and a bit more planning — it's not automatic as Tcl and JSON have really very different concepts of types.

Comment: If you've got something specific you want to achieve, do ask another question with more detail so that it will guide us better to a helpful answer.

Comment: thanks a lot ! yes it turned into a json list :) I wanted to use it to keep changing the content of a select list based on the change that happens in the tcl array :D Many thanks @Donal Fellows